in an $m \times n$ grid, prove that if $m$ and $n$ are odd, then there is no hamiltonian cycle
Let a simple undirected graph $G=(V,E)$ be defined by $V=\{1,2,...,m\} \times \{1,2,...,n\}$ and $E=E_1 \cup E_2$ where
$$\begin{split}
E_1 &= \{((a,b),(a+1&,b&)) &\; | 1 \leq a \leq m-1 &,\; 1 \leq b \leq n &\} \\
E_2 &= \{((a,b),(a&,b+1&)) &\; | 1 \leq a \leq m &,\; 1 \leq b \leq n-1 &\}
\end{split}$$
Prove that if $2 \leq m, 2 \leq n$ and $2 \not| mn$, then there doesn't exist a Hamiltonian cycle in $G$.
this question came right after the question: "Prove that if $2 \leq m,2 \leq n$ and $2 | mn$, then in $G$ there is a Hamiltonian cycle. A question that I solved. Maybe someone could use that question to answer this one.
Now here is what I think to use for the main question:
I tried using the fact (*) that the graph is bipartite. Maybe I can do something with the 2 sides of the bipartite graph having to be equal for a Hamiltonian cycle?
I now come back to this question, I think I can do this: Since $m,n$ is odd, then $|V|=mn$ is also odd, which means there cannot be 2 equal sides in the bipartite graph, which means it doesn't have a hamiltonian cycle.
I can't find my class notes right now, so if someone can confirm that theorem (*) is indeed correct, that would be great. And if not, then someone help me out here please

The question which you say that came after your question is the same again, no?

the main question with $m$ and $n$ being odd came after $m$ or $n$ or both being even

Then did you mean to write $2\nmid mn$ in the first one you wrote?

yes, now the question is edited to fix that.

@YanivPolischuk You didn't put your main question at the start, edited that now. Also you (*) theorem is correct which you can prove via induction

the theorem, we proved it in class so I can use it. So I guess my answer is correct so thank you

For $m$ and $n$ both being odd, color the grid like a chessboard. Say the corners are all white. The number of white cells are $1$ more than the number of black cells.
Any Hamiltonian cycle would traverse an equal number of white and black cells, so there cannot be any.
